# Check if drive has enough space for backup

Tags: batch-file, automation, backup

I'm busy automating backups with bat scripts. Can I compare the available space on the external to the size of the backup data?

Want to make sure there is enough space for data that needs to back up and if there isn't I need it to send me a mail. ( i know how to send emails and stuff, just need to know how to check the disk space)

Comment: I'd suggest that checking the available space isn't the hardest part, checking one value against the other is more likely to be. Perhaps [this question from only yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51057439) will give you some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3" %%s IN (`DIR C:\ /-C /-O /W`) DO (
 SET FREE=%%s
)
ECHO %FREE%
```

Remember to change C:\ to the external drives letter.

Comment: Could you maybe Explain what each command does? im still new to this and trying to learn as much as i can

Comment: @Wade, to find out what each command does, open a Command Prompt, _`cmd.exe`_, window and type the name of the command followed by a forward slash and question mark. e.g. `FOR /?` or `DIR /?` or `SET /?` or ECHO /?`

Comment: If you are running a batch file from a partition for which you need to know the free space, you can use `%~d0` instead of the drive letter `DIR %~d0\ /-C /-O /W`